# How to perform element-wise scalar operations on a vector with Scala Breeze?

Tags: scala, scala-breeze, scalala

With Scalala it was possible to perform element-wise operations on a Vector using a scalar operand.  Say you have a Vector of random numbers between 0 and 1 and you want to subtract each value from 1:

```
import breeze.linalg._

val x = DenseVector.rand(5)
val y = 1d :- x  //DOESN'T COMPILE: "value :- is not a member of Double"
```

Unlike Scalala, Breeze fails to compile with this approach.  You can work around this by generating a Vector of ones but it just seems like there should be a better way.

```
val y = DenseVector.ones[Double](x.size) :- x
```

Another workaround would be to use the mapValues method which is a bit more readable:

```
val y = x mapValues { 1 - _ }
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this with Breeze?

Comment: You don't want to write `val y = -x + 1d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question and is sligthly outdated. Currently, with breeze `1.0` and scala `2.11` this syntax is now supported:

```
import breeze.linalg._

val x = DenseVector.rand(5)
val y = 1d :- x
```

Output:

```
import breeze.linalg._
x: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.8274425487378012, 0.11585689753323769, 0.9691257294006741, 0.15061939654911782, 0.8337942418593918)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
y: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.1725574512621988, 0.8841431024667623, 0.030874270599325904, 0.8493806034508822, 0.16620575814060823)
```